# SAS incorrect joining

Tags: sql, sas, outer-join

I have two datasets in SAS:

```
Name acct date      id1       Name acct date     id2
a    123  12/10/22  1         a    123  12/10/22 1
a    123  12/10/22  1         a    123  12/10/22 .
a    123  12/10/22  .         a    123  12/10/22 1
                              a    123  12/10/22 1
```

I want output like:

```
Name acct date     id1   id2
a    123  12/10/22  1    1
a    123  12/10/22  1    .
a    123  12/10/22  .    1
a    123  12/10/22  .    1
```

My joining keys are `acct` and `date`.

```
proc sql; 
    create table new as 
        select a.* , b.id2 
        from table1 a 
        full join table2 b 
        on a.acct=b.acct and a.date=b.date
    ;
quit;
```

When I am running a full join, it is giving `id1` as `1` throughout. What is a way to fix this?

Comment: Show us your current FULL JOIN query.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: SQL, by definition, does not guarantee to preserve order. It is NOT suited to do what you try to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use SQL at all?  It looks to me like you just want to MERGE the datasets.

```
data one ;
  input Name $ acct $ date :mmddyy. id1 ;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
a    123  12/10/22  1       
a    123  12/10/22  1       
a    123  12/10/22  .       
;

data two ;
  input Name $ acct $ date :mmddyy. id2 ;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
a    123  12/10/22 1
a    123  12/10/22 .
a    123  12/10/22 1
a    123  12/10/22 1
;

data want;
  merge one two;
  by name acct date ;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    Name    acct          date    id1    id2

 1      a      123     2022-12-10     1      1
 2      a      123     2022-12-10     1      .
 3      a      123     2022-12-10     .      1
 4      a      123     2022-12-10     .      1
```

If you wanted to recreate that in SQL (at least for this simple data) then the easiest way is to use NATURAL join.  Then SAS will automatically join on the common variables and coalesce them.

```
proc sql;
create table want as select * from have2 natural full join have1 ;
quit;
```